# PostgreSQL vs SQLite

Tags: postgresql, query, sqlite

I was wondering because recently I installed PostgreSQL, and I have previously installed DB Browser for SQLite on my Windows 10 computer. If it PostgreSQL has a DB Browser GUI for the tables, because I was using it and I was using SQL Query language to create a table, and insert values into the table. I thought this question would be on topic for the site, if its not please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

pgAdmin is the most recommended GUI tool for querying PostgreSQL: https://www.pgadmin.org/

Here's a list of other recommendations too: [https://scalegrid.io/blog/which-is-the-best-postgresql-gui-2019-comparison/#:~:text=pgAdmin%20is%20the%20de%20facto,and%20developers%20for%20database%20administration](https://scalegrid.io/blog/which-is-the-best-postgresql-gui-2019-comparison/#:%7E:text=pgAdmin%20is%20the%20de%20facto,and%20developers%20for%20database%20administration).

Comment: Dbeaver and Heidisql are pretty good alternatives.

Comment: Yup, I've heard good things about DBeaver, but mostly have used pgAdmin.